# Swift Syntax Error : Type 'AnyObject' cannot be implicitly downcast

Tags: swift, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-swift

I used below code to create sprite in swift.

```
    var bg : CCSprite = CCSprite.spriteWithImageNamed("Default.png");
    bg.position = ccp(SW*0.5, SH*0.5)
    self.addChild(bg)
```

Please check image, its giving error for 1st line.[image]

Error : Type 'AnyObject' cannot be implicitly downcast to 'CCNode': did you mean to use 'as' to force downcast?

Is there any Cocos2d-Swift documents online ?

Comment: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/docs/api/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rewrite

```
var bg : CCSprite = CCSprite.spriteWithImageNamed("Default.png")
```

as

```
var bg = CCSprite.spriteWithImageNamed("Default.png") as CCSprite
```

Swift does not implicitly convert (in this case: `AnyObject!` to `CCSprite`),
you have to add an explicit cast with `as`.